# I installed Unity Hub and Unity but I have to run hub using the DL file. Can I make it appear in apps or pin it to dock somehow?

Tags: ubuntu-dock, unity3d

Installed Unity following this guideline https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GettingStartedInstallingHub.html

The file type is AppImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely forgot about this. A friend helped me out in the end. [This](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher) is how we solved it

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem, can't find how to open the Hub as it does not appear in my list of applications or anywhere else. What I did was the following:

- I saved unityhub.appimage in my unity folder.
- I then set it up to open when the system starts so it goes in the system tray and is available anytime. (I do this by going to "Session Settings > Autostart > Add")

It's not the best but it works for me, I hope this helps.